# How to invoke toggle button in list view?

Tags: android, android-listview

hi I have made an Application that shows installed application in list view and have toggle button with each row.
I want to show a Toast that display app name when corresponding Switch/toggle button is clicked....

Error: when i click toggle button it is not showing corresponding app name but it it is showing other app name....

Source project : you can download the complete source/project from here ------>  http://www.ziddu.com/download/23238098/ApplicationViewer1.rar.html

please need ur help

the classes are as follows

```
package com.tech.ashu;

import java.util.List;

import pete.android.study.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
    private PackageManager mPackManager;`enter code here`
    ApplicationInfo entry;
    TextView tvAppName;

    public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List<ApplicationInfo> list, PackageManager pm) {
        mContext = c;
        mListAppInfo = list;
        mPackManager = pm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the selected entry
        entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        // reference to convertView
        View v = convertView;

        // inflate new layout if null
        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
        }

        // load controls from layout resources
        ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        Switch s= (Switch)v.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
        //TextView tvPkgName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);

        // set data to display
        ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));

        if (s != null) 
        {
            s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("tag", "switch1 is null");
        }

        //tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);

        // return view
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+entry.loadLabel(mPackManager), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at your method:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+entry.loadLabel(mPackManager), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Here you are only using two variables to get the text (`entry` and `mPackManager`). You are setting `entry` to `mListAppInfo.get(i)` in your `getView()` method. This wont work because this makes `entry` the `ApplicationInfo` associated with the last loaded `View`, which most likely is the bottom (or top) visible view. Which means, when you check an item in the the  list, `entry` will probably not be the `ApplicationInfo` to the view you checked.

So what can we do? What we want is the `ApplicationContext` to the checked item, and the item is given to us in the `onCheckedChanged` method, as `buttonView`. So what about this:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
    // This is the TextView you found, and set the text for in getView()
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    String appName = tv.getText();

    Toast.makeText(mContext, appName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This isn't perfect, though. You probably want more than just the name of the app clicked, but the `ApplicationContext` isn't stored in the `ListView` item, so without making any changes to the code, we can't do much more than this.

What you can do, if you want the `entry` variable to point to the clicked `item`, is to extend `ArrayAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter`, and `Override` the `onItemClicked()` method, as an `int index`  is supplied. To get your `ApplicationContext` you would just write `mListAppInfo.get(index);`

---

Note:

I think it would be better not to post the whole code in a `.rar`, but post the relevant classes in `Gist`, or `PasteBin`, or something similar.